# Build an array of nested objects from arrays of properties names and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I´m building an integration package for a legacy system where I receive all data, including the data structure definition (metadata) using lists.

Fields (or properties) in metadata list changes depeding on what type of record is being retrieved. The example below shows a customer record, but it may be a product record, or a stock item record - then I would receive different metadata.

I need to dynamically build the object structure from the metadata and then fetch its data from the given lists.

`metadata` list for a customer call to legacy system:

```
[
    {
        field: "customer.id",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.name",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.credit.rate",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.credit.card.limit",
        type: "number"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.credit.card.due",
        type: "number"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.credit.card.paymentDay",
        type: "number"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.address.street",
        type: "string"
    },
    {   
        field: "customer.address.number",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "customer.address.zip",
        type: "string"
    }
]
```

`metadata` list for a product call to legacy system:

```
[
    {
        field: "product.id",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "product.name",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "product.sale.customer.id",
        type: "string"
    },
    {
        field: "product.sale.customer.name",
        type: "number"
    },
    {
        field: "product.sale.price",
        type: "number"
    }
]
```

`products` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", product_id: "1", name: "Spounge" },
    { id: "2", product_id: "2", name: "CD Box" },
]
```

`customers` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", name: "John"},
    { id: "2", name: "Mary"}
]
```

`credits` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", customer_id: "1", rate: "A" },
    { id: "2", customer_id: "2", rate: "B" },
]
```

`cards` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", credit_id: "1", limit: 10000, due: 0, paymentDay: 15 },
    { id: "2", credit_id: "2", limit: 1000, due: 1000, paymentDay: 2 },
]
```

`address` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", customer_id: "1", street: "46th St", number: "33", zip: "12312" },
    { id: "2", customer_id: "2", street: "55th Avenue", number: "349", zip: "39458" },
]
```

`products` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", product_id: "1", name: "Spounge" },
    { id: "2", product_id: "2", name: "CD Box" },
]
```

`customers` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", name: "John"},
    { id: "2", name: "Mary"}
]
```

`credits` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", customer_id: "1", rate: "A" },
    { id: "2", customer_id: "2", rate: "B" },
]
```

`cards` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", credit_id: "1", limit: 10000, due: 0, paymentDay: 15 },
    { id: "2", credit_id: "2", limit: 1000, due: 1000, paymentDay: 2 },
]
```

`sales` list:

```
[
    { id: "1", customer_id: "1", product_id: "1", price: 123.44 },
    { id: "2", customer_id: "2", product_id: "2", price: 3.22 },
]
```

My goal is to have that data in a single javascript array of objects:

Example for the customer call to legacy system:

```
customers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "John",
        credit {
            rate: "A",
            card {
                limit: 10000,
                due: 0,
                paymentDay: 15
            }
        },
        address {
            street: "46th St",
            number: "33",
            zip: "12312"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mary",
        credit {
            rate: "B",
            card {
                limit: 1000,
                due: 1000,
                paymentDay: 2
            }
        },
        address {
            street: "55th Avenue",
            number: "349",
            zip: "39458"
        }
    }
]
```

Example for the product call to legacy system:

```
customers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Spounge",
        sale {
            price: 123.44,
            customer {
                id: "1",
                name: "John"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "CD Box",
        sale {
            price: 3.22,
            customer {
                id: "2",
                name: "Mary"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I´m really very confused finding the right way of doing this. What would be the best approach to start from? Start from building a nested object and filling it up? Any suggested algorithm?

NOTE: The legacy system changes the data based on the type of object is being read and data availability. So, `metadata` list and the lists are not fixed. For every API call into the legacy system I receive a different metadata array and different lists, depending on what data is available and the query is being made, so I need a generic algorithm to build the object based on the given data.

Comment: do you have the lists or are they what you want to get from the metadata?

Comment: Final result must come the lists based on the metadata. Both may change.

Comment: you'd go through the fields, split by ".", and created object accordingly.  For example: "customer.credit.card.limit" - check if customer exists and create one if not, within customer, check if credit exists and create one if not, within credit, check if card exists and create one if not, and within card, check if limit exists and create one if not.  consider/plan for possibility one customer has multiple cards, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses a data base with the given relations between the named arrays (aka tables) and creates an object with the relations for a faster access.

The relations, like n : m are collected but only the first (or only) 1 : 1 relation is used.

```js
const
    getDatabase = data => Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [table, rows]) => {
            r[table] = r[table] || {};
            rows.forEach(row => {
                r[table][row.id] = row;
                Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, id]) => {
                    const
                        getObject = (object, keys) => keys.reduce((o, k, i, { length }) => o[k] = o[k] || (i + 1 === length ? [] : {}), object),
                        [reference, suffix] = key.split('_');

                    if (!suffix) return;

                    getObject(r.relations, [table, row.id, reference]).push(id);
                    getObject(r.relations, [reference, id, table]).push(row.id);
                });
            });
            return r;
        }, { relations: {} }),
    getDatasets = (db, table, metadata) => Object
        .values(db[table])
        .map(data => {
            const references = [[table, data.id]];

            return metadata.reduce((target, { field }) => {
                let source = data,
                    path = field.split('.'),
                    last = path.pop();

                path
                    .reduce((t, k) => {
                        if (k in db) {
                            let i = references.length;
                            while (i--) {
                                const
                                    [table, id] = references[i],
                                    temp = db.relations[table]?.[id]?.[k];

                                if (!temp) continue;
                                source = db[k][temp[0]];
                                if (!references.some(a => a[0] === k && a[1] === source.id)) {
                                    references.push([k, source.id]);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return t[k] = t[k] || {};
                    }, target)
                    [last] = source[last];

                return target;
            }, {});
        }),
    customer = [{ id: "customer1", name: "John" }, { id: "customer2", name: "Mary" }],
    credit = [{ id: "credit1000", customer_id: "customer1", rate: "A" }, { id: "credit2000", customer_id: "customer2", rate: "B" }],
    card = [{ id: "card1", credit_id: "credit1000", limit: 10000, due: 0, paymentDay: 15 }, { id: "card2", credit_id: "credit2000", limit: 1000, due: 1000, paymentDay: 2 }],
    address = [{ id: "address1", customer_id: "customer1", street: "46th St", number: "33", zip: "12312" }, { id: "address2", customer_id: "customer2", street: "55th Avenue", number: "349", zip: "39458" }],
    product = [{ id: "product1", name: "Spounge" }, { id: "product2", name: "CD Box" }],
    sale = [{ id: "sale1", customer_id: "customer1", product_id: "product1", price: 123.44 }, { id: "sale2", customer_id: "customer2", product_id: "product2", price: 3.22 }],
    db = getDatabase({ customer, credit, card, address, product, sale }),
    metadata1 = [{ field: "customer.id", type: "string" }, { field: "customer.name", type: "string" }, { field: "customer.credit.rate", type: "string" }, { field: "customer.credit.card.limit", type: "number" }, { field: "customer.credit.card.due", type: "number" }, { field: "customer.credit.card.paymentDay", type: "number" }, { field: "customer.address.street", type: "string" }, { field: "customer.address.number", type: "string" }, { field: "customer.address.zip", type: "string" }],
    metadata2 = [{ field: "product.id", type: "string" }, { field: "product.name", type: "string" }, { field: "product.sale.customer.id", type: "string" }, { field: "product.sale.customer.name", type: "number" }, { field: "product.sale.price", type: "number" }],
    customers = getDatasets(db, 'customer', metadata1),
    products = getDatasets(db, 'product', metadata2);

console.log(customers);
console.log(products);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Really impressive code Nina. Thanks. I'm just trying to find out how it works.... Where do you filter the lists(data) according to a given `customer_id` or `whatever_id`...

Comment: `metadata` is taking control over the used properties.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to filter the list for its `customer_id` ie. I'm trying to find out your magic... rs

Comment: @Mendes, the solution now respects the given relation. the former verion just took the values form the arrays of the same index. this is gone. now the `id` is working as primary key and all relations are stored as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could first iterate through each `customer` and then each `metadata` entry which you will use to build nested structure. On each new field you can check if the current key exists in levels and if it does you get the correct value for it.

```js
const metadata = [{"field":"customer.id","type":"string"},{"field":"customer.name","type":"string"},{"field":"customer.credit.rate","type":"string"},{"field":"customer.credit.card.limit","type":"number"},{"field":"customer.credit.card.due","type":"number"},{"field":"customer.credit.card.paymentDay","type":"number"},{"field":"customer.address.street","type":"string"},{"field":"customer.address.number","type":"string"},{"field":"customer.address.zip","type":"string"}]
const customers = [{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Mary"}]
const credits = [{"id":"1","customer_id":"1","rate":"A"},{"id":"2","customer_id":"2","rate":"B"}]
const cards = [{"id":"1","credit_id":"1","limit":10000,"due":0,"paymentDay":15},{"id":"2","credit_id":"2","limit":1000,"due":1000,"paymentDay":2}]
const address = [{"id":"1","customer_id":"1","street":"46th St","number":"33","zip":"12312"},{"id":"2","customer_id":"2","street":"55th Avenue","number":"349","zip":"39458"}]

const result = []
const levels = {
  customer: customers,
  credit: credits,
  card: cards,
  address: address
}

const rootKey = metadata[0].field.split('.')[0]
const getLevel = (data, key, pKey, id) => {
  return data[key].find(e => {
    return e[`${pKey}_id`] == id
  })
}

levels[rootKey].forEach(object => {
  let customer = {}

  metadata.forEach(({ field, type }) => {
    let pId = object.id;
    let pKey = rootKey;
    let level = object;

    field.split('.').reduce((r, key, i, arr) => {
      if (i > 0 && key in levels) {
        level = getLevel(levels, key, pKey, pId) || {}

        if (level) {
          pKey = key;
          pId = level.id
        }
      }

      if (!arr[i + 1]) {
        r[key] = level[key]
        return r[key]
      }

      return r[key] = r[key] || {}
    }, customer)
  })

  result.push(customer.customer);
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Metadata changes. At one call `customer` is the main object. Another call `sale` is the object, and so forth. See my comments. Coding metadata names and levels does will not make it  work. This is the tricky piece...

Comment: @Mendes See update, you could get root key and use that.

Comment: Added new example. In the way to get there, but levels are still tied to metadata names....

Comment: Do you have in mind some other way to connect the metadata names and levels. Since you have customers, credits etc in separate arrays I don't see other way to connect those two.

Comment: No. In fact I cannot change that spec  as this comes from a list based old system. My goal is to convert those wird logic into a javascript object so that I can work on my application.

Comment: So could you be specific on what is the problem now with this implementation?

Comment: Can´t find a way to implement it. Algorithm problem...